# Passing Web Api Nhibernate Session to Controller

Tags: c#, session, nhibernate, dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api

I have added a new WebApi project to my solution and Controllers Get Method calls a function which returns an Xml . Am calling an function which uses a Nhibernate ISession to instantiate . Am using MySql for my Db I get the following error.

Here is a trace of the error

```
<Error>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>System.NullReferenceException</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace>
at comp.rest.RestApi.Controllers.RestApiController.Get() in C:\GitHub\rea-rest\src\comp.rest.RestApi\Controllers\RestApiController.cs:line 23 at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] ) at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass13.<GetExecutor>b__c(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters) at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments) at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.<>c__DisplayClass5.<ExecuteAsync>b__4() at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpers.RunSynchronously[TResult](Func`1 func, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
</StackTrace>
</Error>
```

I do have a dependency resolver which i call from the global.asax file on app start

```
public class ApiDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
    {
        private static ISession _session;
        private static ISettings _settings;
        private static IDiscountService _discountService;
        private static IAuctionService _auctionService;
        private static IAuditService _auditService;

        private NhProductAdminService productAdminService = new NhProductAdminService(_session, _settings,
                                                                                             _discountService,
                                                                                             _auctionService,
                                                                                             _auditService);

        public IDependencyScope BeginScope()
        {
            // This example does not support child scopes, so we simply return 'this'.
            return this;
        }

        public object GetService(Type serviceType)
        {
            if (serviceType == typeof(RestApiController))
            {
                return new RestApiController(productAdminService);
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
        {
            return new List<object>();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            // When BeginScope returns 'this', the Dispose method must be a no-op.
        }

    }
```

Usually has the Nhibernate session instantiated once the controller is hit this is because we have already opened a session in the global.asax Application_Start, I am stuck at this for a few days now , Would be great for anyone to help me out , Am sure am doing something silly . Am new to WebApi .

In our Web Application we Open the Nhibernate Session using the global.asax .

```
builder.RegisterModule(new WebNHibernateModule());
var container = builder.Build();
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
```

The WebHibernate Class looks like this

```
public class WebNHibernateModule : NHibernateModule
    {
        protected override IPersistenceConfigurer DatabaseConfig
        {
            get
            {
                return 
                    MySQLConfiguration.Standard
                        .ConnectionString(s => s.FromConnectionStringWithKey("ApplicationServices"))
                        .Driver<ProfiledSqlClientDriver>();
                //.ShowSql();
            }
        }

        protected override Action<MappingConfiguration> MappingConfig
        {
            get { return AutoConfig.Mappings; }
        }
    }

    public class ProfiledSqlClientDriver : MySqlDataDriver
    {
        public override IDbCommand CreateCommand()
        {
            var command = base.CreateCommand();

            if (MiniProfiler.Current != null)
            {
                command = DbCommandProxy.CreateProxy(command);
            }

            return command;
        }
    }
```

The NHibernateModule Class looks like this

```
public abstract class NHibernateModule : Module
    {
        protected abstract IPersistenceConfigurer DatabaseConfig { get; }
        protected abstract Action<MappingConfiguration> MappingConfig { get; }

        protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(NhSessionQueryable<>)).As(typeof(IQueryable<>));
            builder.RegisterType<NhQueryContext>().As<IQueryContext>();

            builder.RegisterType<WebSessionTracker>().As<ISessionTracker>()
                .InstancePerHttpRequest();

            builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<ISessionFactory>().OpenSession())
                .InstancePerHttpRequest()
                .OnActivated(e =>
                {
                    e.Context.Resolve<ISessionTracker>().CurrentSession = e.Instance;
                    e.Instance.BeginTransaction();
                });

            builder.Register(c =>
                    Fluently.Configure().Database(DatabaseConfig)
                    .Mappings(MappingConfig)
                    .BuildConfiguration())
                .SingleInstance()
                .OnActivated(e =>
                {
                    e.Instance.Initialize(e.Context.Resolve<ValidatorEngine>());
                    new SchemaValidator(e.Instance).Validate(); // Validate the schema when we create the session factory
                });

            builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<Configuration>().BuildSessionFactory())
                .SingleInstance();
        }
    }
```

Usually in our Web Application similar Autofac is used to prepopulate the session ,
Am doing the same for the WebApi as well , but the Nhibernate Session is still null .

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have some confusion over the term "session"...

> MVC usually has the session instantiated once the controller is hit

An NHibernate session is not the same thing as ASP.NET (MVC) session.  You create an NHibernate session with `ISessionFactory.OpenSession()`.  See [chapter 3 of the documentation](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#session-configuration) for a more detailed explanation of how to get an NHibernate session.

Comment: Thank you Daniel . I think i have mislead you guys here . I was actually referring to ISessionfactory's Session . I know that in our normal web projects this session is already instantiated when the application launches due to the logic in Global.asax , But for a Webapi when I use the same logic and web.config it doesnt work . I hope i have clarified my problem . Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I could not find a reason to why the dependencies werent resolved , But i worked around and used a Normal controller to return an XML . Most blog i read asked register APIControllers as well .